# Google Apps Script - If Date = Today, Highlight Row

Tags: date, google-apps-script, dst

I have a cell that contains a manually set date. If this date = today, I want to highlight the entire row. I thought I had this working just fine, but Daylight Savings Time has thrown a giant wrench into my date comparison. Can anyone help?

Right now, if my cell contains "3/15/2017", the script will tell me the date is equal to "3/14/2017". I know it's taking an hour off of because of DST, but I don't know how to remedy this while comparing my dates. Existing code below.

```
function highlightRow (selectionRow) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test Sheet");
  var dateToFlag = sheet.getRange(selectionRow,27).getValue();
  var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (dateToFlag !== "" && dateToFlag == today) {
      sheet.getRange(selectionRow,1,1,50).setBackgroundColor('yellow');
    }
```

}

Comment: We don't know that the value for `sheet.getRange(selectionRow,27)` is.  Add a `Logger.log('dateToFlag: ' + dateToFlag)` statement; run the code and VIEW the LOGS.  Then tell us what the value is.  The script editor has it's own time zone.  I'm not saying that this is the solution, but you can change the time zone in the code editor.  Also, what does this line `today.setHours(0,0,0,0);` do?  What is that for?

Comment: sheet.getRange(selectionRow,27).getValue() is 3/15/2017 - the date manually inputted into my spreadsheet. However, when I log this, it appears as 3/14/2017 23:00:00. 

My setHours was meant to set the time to 00:00:00 so I only have to worry about the dates matching, not the times.

Comment: UPDATE: @Sandy I am outputting the dates via Broswer.msgbox and they appear to be identical, but are not triggering my if statement to highlight row. Here's how the dates appear in the msgbox.  
  
Date = Tue Mar 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Today = Tue Mar 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

Comment: The msgbox may be displaying the same value, but the data types of the variables may be different.  You should check the data type of both variables to determine if they are the same.  `typeof Date`  [Link to Data types Info](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here this seems to work now by formatting the dates a little.  I modified the code a little to get it to work in my editor.  The problem is that one contained time and the other didn't.

```
function highlightRow () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dateToFlagS = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var dateToFlag = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateToFlagS), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (dateToFlag !== "" && dateToFlag == today) 
    {
      sheet.getRange(1,1,1,50).setBackgroundColor('yellow');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Date stored in Google Sheets actually stores time in milliseconds since Epoch. If you are concerned with date alone and not bothered about time, it is sensible to set the time as zero hours with that date. This would make date comparison logic work properly.